# VBA LIFO stack dynamic range

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have the code for a LIFO stack that goes through data on each day and, after iterating through all the data, it prints the LIFO stack. However, I want to repeat this process every single day, so on day 2 it will calculate the stack given the data on day 2 and day 1, for day 3 it will use day 3, 2, and 1 data until day N where it will stop this loop. The current code is below. I tried to create a variable that increments for the end of the range but I kept getting errors that the type was not matched for the line `For i = LBound(dataArr, 1) To UBound(dataArr, 1)`

```
Option Explicit

Dim myStack() As Variant
Dim pricesStacked() As Variant
Dim stackCount As Long

Sub ProcessDataWithStack()
    Dim dataColumn As Range
    Dim priceColumn As Range
    Dim dataArr As Variant
    Dim priceArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim resultSheet As Worksheet
    Dim outputRange As Range
    
    ' Set the range for the data column (replace "A1:A10" with the actual range)
    Set dataColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    
    ' Set the range for the price column (replace "B1:B10" with the actual range)
    Set priceColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B10")
    
    ' Read the data and price values into arrays
    dataArr = dataColumn.Value
    priceArr = priceColumn.Value
    
    ReDim myStack(1 To dataColumn.Rows.Count)
    ReDim pricesStacked(1 To dataColumn.Rows.Count)
    stackCount = 0
    
    ' Process the data
    For i = LBound(dataArr, 1) To UBound(dataArr, 1)
        Dim dataValue As Variant
        Dim priceValue As Variant
        
        dataValue = dataArr(i, 1)
        priceValue = priceArr(i, 1)
        
        If dataValue > 0 Then
            stackCount = stackCount + 1
            myStack(stackCount) = dataValue
            pricesStacked(stackCount) = priceValue
        Else
            While stackCount > 0 And myStack(stackCount) + dataValue < 0
                dataValue = dataValue + myStack(stackCount)
                stackCount = stackCount - 1
            Wend
            
            If stackCount > 0 Then
                myStack(stackCount) = myStack(stackCount) + dataValue
            End If
            pricesStacked(stackCount + 1) = priceValue
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Check if there are any existing sheets named "Output" and delete them
    Dim existingSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set existingSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not existingSheet Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        existingSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    ' Create a new sheet for output
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set resultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    resultSheet.Name = "Output"
    
    ' Define the output range on the new sheet
    Set outputRange = resultSheet.Range("A1:B" & stackCount)
    
    ' Write the resulting stack and corresponding prices to the output range
    outputRange.Columns(1).Value = Application.Transpose(myStack)
    outputRange.Columns(2).Value = Application.Transpose(pricesStacked)
    
    ' Optional: Format the output range as desired
    outputRange.NumberFormat = "0"
    
    ' Inform the user of the completed process
    MsgBox "Process completed. Resulting stack and corresponding prices are printed to the 'Output' sheet."
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred while creating the 'Output' sheet."
End Sub
type here
```

This is code I made in python that works but I'm not able to translate it into VBA

```py
from collections import deque
myStack = deque()
data = [1800, 11 , -10, 15, 7, -20]
prices = [1, 1.50, .75, 1.25, 1.4, 9]
dates = ["1/1/2010", "1/2/2010", "1/3/2010", "1/4/2010", "1/5/2010", "1/6/2010"]
pricesStacked = []
count = 0

for i in data:

    if i > 0:
        myStack.append(i)
        pricesStacked.append(prices[count])
        count += 1
    else:
        if abs(i) < myStack[-1]:
            myStack[-1] += i
            count += 1
        else:
            while abs(i) >= myStack[-1]:
                i = i + myStack[-1]
                myStack.pop()
                pricesStacked.pop()
            myStack[-1] += i
            count += 1
    for i in range(len(myStack)):
        print(myStack[i])
        print(pricesStacked[i])
        print(dates[count - 1])
```

I was expecting it to output the stack on each day, so the output I want is the date and each element of the stack on that date.

Comment: Your VBA code has no date data ?

Comment: Can you confirm the line at which the error occurs (ie in the error dialog press 'Debug' and see which line is highlighted) and the exact error number and text

Comment: "ataArr = dataColumn.Value" will return a two-dimensional array -- a n by 1 column, but I think it's an array of arrays, not an nx1 array. Try leaving out the 'dimension' parameter?